# apply background image (parent) and still keep background color

Tags: html, css

How I can apply `top` background image for `menu` and still keep background color?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="top">
    <div class="menu">
        Nop.
    </div>
    Nam hendrerit erat eget tellus mollis facilisis. Mauris eget est ullamcorper, cursus massa quis, sollicitudin nulla. Vivamus rutrum blandit odio, vitae iaculis velit placerat et. Praesent et mauris et massa molestie laoreet. Phasellus pharetra id leo sit amet semper. Pellentesque ipsum velit, viverra non turpis nec, tristique consequat velit. In felis erat, ullamcorper ut ultricies ac, feugiat malesuada nunc.
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.top {
    background: url('http://d1c739w2xm33i4.cloudfront.net/2.2/top_image.jpg');
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.top .menu {
    background: #dedede;
}
```

and here's the *JSFiddle*: http://jsfiddle.net/ZXeQk/

My code is not exactly ok, I want to apply opacity only for background image and include `menu` too. I hope you understand. Thanks!

**Edit:** Here (http://i.imm.io/1io9t.png) is a image with what I want.

Comment: can you show image of what you trying to do?

Comment: did you try to use `rbga` for `background-color background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fall-back for browsers that don't support rgba */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5;`

Answer (score 0):

For support on browsers > ie8 you can use a rgba value to make your menu semi-transparent.

```
.top .menu {
    background: rgba(222,222,222,0.7);
}
```

If you want your background-image to also be transparent it'd be better to save it as a transparent png.